# Initializing a form with response data from an API in react-admin/react

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

In my react-admin app there is a form `FooCreate`. When opening this form I'd like to populate the default values for the form elements with data retrieved from an external API.

I have read that `componentDidMount()` often is the preferred place where to call external APIs. The URL gets called but I have no idea how I can pass the response data to my `FooCreate` form.

How can I

```
class MyCreate extends Create {
    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const response = await API.get("/foo");
            // response contains a field like response.name
            // How can populate the below FooCreate with default values retrieved in response?
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
}

export const FooCreate = props => (
    <MyCreate {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            {/* This input element shall be populated with the value from response.name */}
            <DisabledInput source="name" defaultValue="John Doe" />
        </SimpleForm>
    </MyCreate>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like that:

```
class MyCreate extends Create {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {};
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const response = await API.get("/foo");
            this.setState({response})
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

   render() {
        return <SimpleForm>
            {this.state.response}
            <DisabledInput source="name" defaultValue="John Doe" />
        </SimpleForm>
   }
}

export const FooCreate = props => (
    <MyCreate {...props} />
);
```